# Mark simonson font not working in IE10 and IE11

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

Below font face was working in edge browser. But it doesn't works on ie10 and ie11. Seems like times new roman font. I have searched for solution in stack overflow. But can't get solution for this problem. Thanks in advance.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.5.0');
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.5.0') format('embedded-opentype'), 
        url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0') format('woff2'),
        url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.0') format('woff'), 
        url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.5.0') format('truetype'), 
        url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.5.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Conv_Mark Simonson - Proxima Nova Regular_0';
    src: url('../fonts/Mark Simonson - Proxima Nova Regular_0.eot');
    src: local('ÃƒÂ¢Ã‹Å“Ã‚Âº'), url('../fonts/Mark Simonson - Proxima Nova Regular_0.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/Mark Simonson - Proxima Nova Regular_0.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/Mark Simonson - Proxima Nova Regular_0.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[first one](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)

[second one](http://www.cssbakery.com/2011/05/fixing-font-face-problems-in-ie.html)

I found two links similar hope it helps you

and also some relevant code

```
   @font-face {
   font-family: 'shardee';
   src: url('fonts/Shardee.eot');
   src: url('fonts/Shardee.eot?#iefix')
   format('embedded-opentype'),
   url('fonts/Shardee.woff') format('woff'),
   url('fonts/Shardee.ttf') format('truetype');
    }
```

again try this
      @font-face
    {
        font-family: "MyFont_Lite";
        src: url("../Fonts/myfont.ttf") format("truetype");
        src: url("../Fonts/myfont.woff") format("woff");
    }

Comment: Checking on this link

Comment: @Parasath V look this one                   http://modernweb.com/2013/07/08/solving-the-problem-of-font-face-inside-media-queries/

Comment: I have tried all these.. But still have the issue

Comment: In IE browser  Security Settings go to Downloads --> Font Downloads. check if it is Disabled then Enable it . i also found this one and   if this is oky then try this  https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/webfont_loader